# How to limit the dynamic textfield to 4 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code for the Createpoll module of my Polling app. I want to generate just 4 dynamic text fields, but the below code generates unlimited text fields. I'm not able to figure out which part to edit to fit my needs.

[Create Poll Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRLVG.jpg)

I'm also unable to make changes to the hint text in the text field, It keeps repeating "Option 1", I want it to go like Option1, Option2.....so on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/Constants.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/screens/create_poll/create_poll2.dart';
import 'package:justpoll/widgets/custom_input.dart';

class CreatePoll extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreatePollState createState() => _CreatePollState();
}

class _CreatePollState extends State<CreatePoll> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _nameController;
  static List<String> friendsList = [null];

  String emoji_id;
  List<String> emoji = [
    "❤️",
    "",
    "✌️",
    "",
    "",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: MyColors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
            child: Text('New Poll'),
          ),
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.close,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    // name textfield

                    Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                        child: Text("1/4"),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32.0),
                      child: CustomInput(
                        textEditingController: _nameController,
                        labletext: 'Question?*',
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Question*'),
                        validator: (v) {
                          if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please enter something';
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),

                    // Text(

                    //   'Options',

                    //   style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16),

                    // ),

                    // Padding(
                    //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0),
                    //   child: Row(
                    //     children: [
                    //       Expanded(
                    //         flex: 2,
                    //         child: Padding(
                    //           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    //           child: CustomInput(
                    //             textEditingController: _nameController,
                    //             labletext: 'Option 1*',
                    //             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Option'),
                    //             validator: (v) {
                    //               if (v.trim().isEmpty)
                    //                 return 'Please enter something';

                    //               return null;
                    //             },
                    //           ),
                    //         ),
                    //       ),
                    //       Expanded(
                    //         flex: 1,
                    //         child: Padding(
                    //           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                    //           child: Container(
                    //             padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 16),
                    //             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    //                 border: Border.all(
                    //                     color: MyColors.black, width: 1.5),
                    //                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    //             child: DropdownButton(
                    //               hint: Text('❤️'),
                    //               value: emoji_id,
                    //               icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    //               iconSize: 36,
                    //               isExpanded: true,
                    //               underline: SizedBox(),
                    //               style: TextType.regularDarkText,
                    //               onChanged: (newValue) {
                    //                 setState(() {
                    //                   emoji_id = newValue;
                    //                 });
                    //               },
                    //               items: emoji.map((emoji_id) {
                    //                 return DropdownMenuItem(
                    //                   value: emoji_id,
                    //                   child: Text(emoji_id),
                    //                 );
                    //               }).toList(),
                    //             ),
                    //           ),
                    //         ),
                    //       ),
                    //     ],
                    //   ),
                    // ),

                    ..._getOptions(),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),

                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CreatePoll2(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        color: Colors.black,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// get friends text-fields
  List<Widget> _getOptions() {
    List<Widget> friendsTextFields = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < friendsList.length; i++) {
      friendsTextFields.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: FriendTextFields(i)),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            // we need add button at last friends row
            _addRemoveButton(i == friendsList.length - 1, i),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
    return friendsTextFields;
  }

  /// add / remove button
  Widget _addRemoveButton(bool add, int index) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (add) {
          // add new text-fields at the top of all friends textfields
          friendsList.insert(0, null);
        } else
          friendsList.removeAt(index);
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 26,
        height: 26,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: (add) ? Colors.black : Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: Icon(
          (add) ? Icons.add : Icons.remove,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FriendTextFields extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  FriendTextFields(this.index);
  @override
  _FriendTextFieldsState createState() => _FriendTextFieldsState();
}

class _FriendTextFieldsState extends State<FriendTextFields> {
  TextEditingController _nameController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String emoji_id;
  List<String> emoji = [
    "❤️",
    "",
    "✌️",
    "",
    "",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _nameController.text = _CreatePollState.friendsList[widget.index] ?? '';
    });

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: CustomInput(
            textEditingController: _nameController,
            labletext: 'Option 1*',
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Option'),
            validator: (v) {
              if (v.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please enter something';

              return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: MyColors.black, width: 1.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: DropdownButton(
                hint: Text('❤️'),
                value: emoji_id,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                iconSize: 36,
                isExpanded: true,
                underline: SizedBox(),
                style: TextType.regularDarkText,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    emoji_id = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: emoji.map((emoji_id) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: emoji_id,
                    child: Text(emoji_id),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, If you want to limit it to just 4 dynamic fields then please replace this line

`_addRemoveButton(i == friendsList.length - 1, i)`

with this

`_addRemoveButton(i < 3 ? i == friendsList.length - 1 : false, i),`

This will make sure that the add button is not shown on the 4th field. Instead it will show the remove button for the 4th field.

Secondly, to have it show each field as Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 etc, replace the line

`labletext: 'Option 1*',`

with

`labletext: 'Option ${widget.index + 1}',`